# Problem with changing the color of a game player object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a small platform game and in that, I made a scene where you can change the colour of your player. I made 3 buttons that change the colour when you click on them. I also made two code files, but they are not working. I see no errors in the console either. 
P.S the colour changing code and buttons are on a different scene than the game object.

This is the code for the buttons that change the colour:

```
using System;              
using System.Collections;                                
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ColourManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static int colour;

    public void DefaultBlue()
    {
        colour = 0;
    }

    public void Green()
    {
        colour = 1;
    }

    public void Red()
    {
        colour = 2;
    }

}
```

This is the code on the game object itself:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ColourTarget : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        rend = GetComponent<Renderer>();

        rend.sharedMaterial = materials[0];

        rend.enabled = true;
    }

    private Renderer rend;

    public int lcolour = ColourManager.colour;
    public Material[] materials;

    private void Update()
    {
        if (lcolour == 0)
        {
            rend.sharedMaterial = materials[0];
        }

        if (lcolour == 1)
        {
            rend.sharedMaterial = materials[1];
        }

        if (lcolour == 2)
        {
            rend.sharedMaterial = materials[2];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Note that changing [`sharedMaterial`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer-sharedMaterial.html) might not  be what you want to do here.

   > If you want to modify the material of a renderer use material instead.

   so rather use [`material`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer-material.html). Especially once e.g. a color was changed and you are dealing with instanced materials, afterwards changing the shared material has no effect at all.
2. Then do not do this in `Update`! It is very redundant and inefficient setting this **every frame**!
3. Finally note that this

   ```
   public int lcolour = ColourManager.colour;
   ```

   is only assigned **ONCE** the moment this object is initialized and then never changed anymore ... `int` is a **VALUE** type, not a reference!

   I would rather use and `event` and make your target listen to any changes.

So your code might look like

```
public class ColourManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static int colour;

    // we will invoke this event everytime the color index is changed
    // and directly pass the according new index in
    public static event Action<int> OnColourIndexChanged;

    public void DefaultBlue()
    {
        colour = 0;

        // The ? is a null check and only 
        // calls Invoke if there is at least one listener to this event
        OnColourIndexChanged?.Invoke(colour);
    }

    public void Green()
    {
        colour = 1;

        OnColourIndexChanged?.Invoke(colour);
    }

    public void Red()
    {
        colour = 2;

        OnColourIndexChanged?.Invoke(colour);
    }
}
```

and then

```
public class ColourTarget : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Renderer _renderer;
    public Material[] materials;

    private void Awake()
    {
        if(!_renderer) _renderer = GetComponent<Renderer>();

        _renderer.enabled = true;

        // Add a callback to the event
        // Removing it first is save also if it wasn't added so far
        // This just makes sure it is always added only exactly once
        ColourManager.OnColourIndexChanged -= UpdateMaterial;
        ColourManager.OnColourIndexChanged += UpdateMaterial;

        // do the first update now with the current state
        UpdateMaterial(ColourManager.colour);
    }

    // Now this is called only when the value is changed in the manager
    // script and once at the beginning with the initial state
    private void UpdateMaterial(int index)
    {
        // check for validity
        if(index < 0 || index >= materials.Length) return;

        _renderer.material = materials[index];
    }

    private void OnDestroy()
    {
        // Always make sure to clean up listeners once not needed anymore
        // otherwise you get NullReferencExceptions
        ColourManager.OnColourIndexChanged -= UpdateMaterial;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your solution i really appreciate it but i also got this solution.  i placed int lcolor == ColourManager.colour in the void Update() ans it worked perfectly fine. Thank you so much for your help anyway.

Comment: @randomdev as said .. doing this in `Update` is no good solution and quite redundant but you do of course what you want ;)